# How to convert Multidemensional Tree Array to a simple Array for use with Select-Combo-Box

Tags: php, arrays

I am struggling with array conversion in PHP.
I have a multidimensional array that returns the following:

var_export($arr)

```
 $array = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'value' => '54',
    'menu_title' => 'EN',
    'page_code' => '54',
    'icon' => 'EN',
    'selected' => '',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'parent' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'value' => '51',
        'menu_title' => '--  Gallery',
        'page_code' => '--  51',
        'icon' => 'none',
        'selected' => '',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'value' => '56',
        'menu_title' => '--  --  another one',
        'page_code' => '--  --  56',
        'icon' => 'none',
        'selected' => '',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'parent' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'value' => '59',
            'menu_title' => '--  --  child of another one',
            'page_code' => '--  --  59',
            'icon' => 'none',
            'selected' => '',
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'parent' => 
            array (
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

however, I need it to convert to something like this:
(var_dump)

```html
Array
(

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 54
                    [menu_title] => EN
                    [page_code] => 54
                    [icon] => EN
                    [selected] => 
                )


            [1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 51
                    [menu_title] => --  Gallery
                    [page_code] => --  51
                    [icon] => none
                    [selected] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 56
                    [menu_title] => --  --  another one
                    [page_code] => --  --  56
                    [icon] => none
                    [selected] => 
                )


            [3] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 59
                    [menu_title] => --  --  child of another one
                    [page_code] => --  --  59
                    [icon] => none
                    [selected] => 
                )
)
```

I am sitting since yesterday on this problem and somehow I can't get it to work as it should.

Thanks for any hints.
Steffano

Comment: please, instead of `var_dump` use `var_export` for the first array, so it can be copy and paste.

Comment: the previous array had a different structure. Also, I don't know why you need nesting when you have `parent_id`.

Comment: With the previous array structure, you can do the [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ed6e9a88ad460d67bbd646da9049a3cfd8651300). However, there's clearly something wrong with your data representation. So I advise you to rethink array structure if you can.

Comment: Hello @sevavietl, you made my day...!!!
Thank you very much!

Comment: @sevavietl, I changed the above array back to the original one so it now matches your code.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need to iterate over nested array the first thing that comes to mind is [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php). As we have complex array, with non-trivial rules for leaves (default rule, as I understand, whether array element is array or not), we need to extend [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) and rewrite two methods: [`hasChildren`](http://php.net/manual/en/recursivearrayiterator.haschildren.php) and [`getChildren`](http://php.net/manual/en/recursivearrayiterator.getchildren.php).

```
class CustomRecursiveArrayIterator extends RecursiveArrayIterator
{
    public function hasChildren()
    {
        return !empty($this->current()['parent']);
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
        $children = array_filter($this->current()['parent'], function ($child) {
            return !isset($child['parent']) || !empty($child['parent']);
        });

        return new static($children);
    }
}
```

Then we can iterator over this iterator and collect all leafs:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new CustomRecursiveArrayIterator($array) 
);

$leafs = [];
foreach ($iterator as $leaf) {
    $leafs[] = $leaf;
}
```

Take a notice this is possible because [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) has mode `RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY`, which is set by default.

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ed6e9a88ad460d67bbd646da9049a3cfd8651300).

As you can see [iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) are pretty powerful, although the documentation is poor.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications. Very useful indeed. I somehow try to avoid those classes usually as, as you said, they are not well documented and I don't quite "get" it. But your clarifications are very helpful and I begin to grasp how powerful these classes really are.
Kind regards, Esteffano

Comment: @Steffano, then you can mark this as the correct answer;)

Comment: How do I do that? Is there a button for this? I'm pretty virgin to this platform. 


Edit: Oh, I think I figured it out, it was the green Arrow, right? :-P